# Factorization of the identity ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need to know if there is a ring $R$, such that if $1_R=f\circ g$ is the composition of two ring homomorphisms, then $f$ is an isomorphism, where $1_R$ is the identity homomorphism on $R$. I appreciate any comment on this question.

Comment: Are your rings commutative with unity?

Comment: So, the condition that you have given us tells us that $f$ is onto (surjective). If $x \in R$ then $f(g(x))=x$. I guess we need to ask if there is an $R$ that forces $f$ to be one-to-one (injective). It's not obvious to me that there is such an $R$.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your homomorphisms are endomorphisms, so go from $R$ to $R$. Since the condition $f\circ g=1_R$ implies that $f$ is surjective, you only need to show that $f$ is innective, so the kernel is zero. This is true if, for example, $R$ is a field (it has no non-trivial ideals), or if $R$ is finite (by cardinality).

Comment: Let R be a ring. Consider the product ring RxR. Then the composition of <1,1> from R to RxR with first projection p from RxR to R is the identity morphism 1_R. But p is not an isomorphism, unless R=0. But then R=0 is not a solution either. So there is no such ring. Is this correct?

Comment: If your honomorphism $f$ is not an endomorphism, so it can go from $R$ to $S$, then only $R=0$ veriifies this property. Note that the diagonal morphism is an isomorphism in this case, so $0\cong 0\times 0$ as rings, an it is the only ring that verifies this.

Comment: R=0 does not work either, because let S be any ring and then you have the zero map from R=0 to S and the zero map from S to R=0, with composition equal to the zero map which equals the identity 1_R from 0 to 0.